# Magento set customer DOB and Taxvat number programatically

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to import the customers using data flow profile and want to set the customer date of birth  and taxvat number as in my csv file i have tried the below code for saving the details but its not working Tried googling the stuffs but can't find right solution..

```
$customer = $this->getCustomerModel();
$customer->setData('dob',date('m-d-Y'));
$customer->setData('taxvat','test');
```

Any one has done this before please help me with this...

Comment: This should work. Do you save() after this?

Answer (score 0):

this should work

but one thing is that by "$this->getCustomerModel();"

you can get oly model, perhaps you have to load customer by load function and then try this.